# Laravel how to in value from controller into render() Eloquent model

Tags: laravel, eloquent

How can one pass in the value from a function inside a controller to the render()?

For example:

```
class LaravelGreat extends Component
{
     public $var1;

     public function DoSomething(){
          $a = 4;
     }

     public function render()
     {
          return view('home', [
           'posts' => DemoModel::
           // HOW TO GET value from DoSomething inside of where
           where('Value1', '=', $a)
      ]);
     }
}
```

Comment: Call the  method, as usual? (Your method is quite useless since it doesn't really set or return anything)

Comment: How do you call a method inside of the render query? Is there any documentation you could provide?

Comment: `$this->DoSomething()` I would assume. Little refresher: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php

Comment: use laravel scope instead of adding a function in a controller which is not nice.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the code below:

```
private function DoSomething(){
  $a = 4;

  return $a;
}

public function render()
{
  $posts = DemoModel::where('Value1', $this->DoSomething())->get();

  return view('home', compact('posts'));
}
```

1.) more readable and maintenable.

2.) if you want to use the equal sign, you can just omit it.

3.) if the method will be used inside the same class, you can make it `private`